# Closing ResultSet twice throws an exception

Tags: java

I recently upgraded the Oracle JDBC driver version from 11.2.0.1 to 12.1.0.1. However, a very strange thing I noticed. In one of my tests I was closing the ResultSet object twice using following code in Java:

```
if (resSet != null) {
            try {
                resSet.getStatement().close();
            } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
                // nothing to do!
                // NullPointerException seen at Oracle and Sybase!
            }
        }
```

This worked without any exception when I used old JDBC driver 11.2.0.1. But when I switch to new JDBC driver 12.1.0.1, it throws an exception:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset: getStatement
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.getStatement(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:272)
```

Why does this happen? When I checked the JavaDoc of ResultSet it says: Calling the method close on a ResultSet object that is already closed is a no-op.

So now I am confused, calling a close twice is a no-op means it shouldn't throw any exception, right?

I am using JDK7u45 with java.sql.ResultSet.

Comment: It might throw RuntimeException or Error. better approach to use try and catch block

Comment: You did not call `close` on a result set, you called `getStatement`.

Comment: I am sorry I didnt mention clearly, I am already using try-catch block. I just need to know why there is a difference in behavior. Updating my question now...

Comment: what is this code supposed purpose? As Henry said, it's `getStatement()` that throw `java.sql.SQLException: Closed Resultset` not `close()`

Comment: I have accepted the answer. Thanks for your comment @Henry.

Comment: But my query still remains: Why does it work with old JDBC driver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As already indicated in the comments, you are not calling `ResultSet.close()`, but calling `ResultSet.getStatement()` followed by a `Statement.close()` instead.

And that call to `resSet.getStatement()` is what throws the exception, as is required by the [JDBC spec/api doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getStatement%28%29):

> **Throws:**
>       `SQLException` - if a database access error occurs or this method is **called on a closed result set**

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

This is correct behaviour in accordance with ResultSet.getStatement API

```
*Throws:

SQLException - if a database access error occurs or this method is called on a closed result set*
```